# How to get the model name or model class of a waterline record?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, watermark, waterline

While different from [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26445699/how-to-get-the-primary-key-attribute-name-of-a-model-waterline-orm) I asked here, it's related and so wanted to link it.

I have been trying hard to find out how I can get the model name (identity) or model *"class"* (exposed in `sails.models`) of a record. So, given a `waterline` record, how can I find out its model name or class?

Example (of course here I know the model is `User` but that is an example):

```
User.findOne(1).exec(function(err, record) {
  // at this point think that we don't know it's a `user` record
  // we just know it's some record of any kind
  // and I want to make some helper so that:
  getTheModelSomehow(record);
  // which would return either a string 'user' or the `User` pseudo-class object
});
```

I have tried to access it with `record.constructor` but that is not `User`, and I couldn't find any property on `record` exposing either the model's pseudo-class object or the record's model name.

UPDATE:
**To clarify, I want a function to which I'll give ANY record, and which would return the model of that record as either the model name or the model pseudo-class object as in `sails.models` namespace.**

```
modelForRecord(record) // => 'user' (or whatever string being the name of the record's model)
```

or

```
modelForRecord(record) // => User (or whatever record's model)
```

Comment: Do you store something else in your User model? Why do you think that it's not a `user` record?

Comment: it's an example, I just want a function which accept a record in parameter, and returns me the model of this record

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WOW, ok after hours of research, here is how I am doing it for those who are interested (it's a very tricky hack, but for now unable to find another way of doing):

Let's say `record` is what you get from a `findOne`, `create`, ... in the callback, to find out what instance it is, and so find the name of the model owning the record, you have to loop over all your models (`sails.models.*`) and make an `instanceof` call this way:

```
function modelFor(record) {
  var model;
  for (var key in sails.models) {
    model = sails.models[key];
    if ( record instanceof model._model.__bindData__[0] ) {
      break;
    }
    model = undefined;
  }
  return model;
}
```

**Do not try to simply do `instanceof model`, that does not work**

After if you need the model name simply `modelFor(record).globalId` to get it.

Comment: I don't know who rate `-1` to my answer but so far it is the only one actually answering the question in all details even if not hacky (NOT saying other answers are useless of course)

Comment: In general, checking object type is not a good programming practice, if you need type checking, you are possibly overcomplicating your logic. Yes, type checking is needed in some cases, but if you are doing it often, possibly you want to revamp your way of doing things.

Comment: Sure but what if you want to do some generic processing depending on some static properties or methods of your model, which waterline will not provide access to thru the instance?

Answer (score 1):

In your model definition why not just create a model attribute. Then the model will be returned with every record call. This will work even after the record become a JSON object.

```
module.exports = {
 attributes : {
      model : {type:'string',default:'User'}
 }
}
```

Comment: No, that would mean I have to add a property/column to all my tables/collections in my database which would be crazy.
Also I don't want to go to a solution where I'd have to add a property/attribute/helper on each model, I want a generic solution where one could put his model definition there and my helper would work.

Comment: That's great. It's a one line change to your model and does have some advantages. I appreciate that it's not the solution for you, but it is still a solution and did not really deserve a downvote. Actually Chetan's solution is probably the best on.

Comment: you add a column in all your db tables just to know the table's name... great?

Comment: Oh, and so far, even if other answers given aren't useless, mine is the only one answering to all the criteria of the question, so thanks for the downvote but it'll not help the community find the right answer

Comment: Not me really, I tend to know the model name already, but if I needed the model name to travel with the record why not. That way when I share with other consumables, they can know the model as well. Your application seems to require the model name without any context in which it might be called. I gave a possible solution, that will work in every context. Maybe not the best, but a perfectly working solution to your question as originally written.

Comment: Sure it's working, but at the cost of adding a column in all your db tables to... know the table name. Also if you are working with external models from a library, you'll then not have the ability to add this attribute. Anyway, FYI adding a column on a table just to know the table name is very bad practice

Comment: How you can call it bad practice without context? Depending on use case it might the best solution. Say the model name is needed by an api consuming the data outside of the context of your application. Or what if the sails is updated and causes breaking changes to your solution? Or what if you move your data to a new framework. Your own comment created a scenario outside sails, but what about outside waterline as well? Now I'm in Chatan's camp as the best solution, but maybe next time be a little more humble when people take time out to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63317/discussion-between-huafu-and-rmeeker).

Answer (score 1):

Use this example for parsing model name

```
var parseModel = function(request) {
    request = request.toLowerCase();
    return sails.models[request];
};
```

and use in controller this code for using this model

```
 parseModel(req.param('modelname')).find().then().catch();
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I commented in the answer from Chetan Shenoy, this is not working if you want to know the model of a record which is not the one related to the request.

Answer (score 0):

Sails exposes everything in the request object. Try grabbing the name of the model this way:

```
var model = req.options.model || req.options.controller;
```

That will give you the raw name. To use it, you'll have to plug the `model` into the sails models array.

```
var Model = req._sails.models[model];
```

Check out the source code to see it in action. (https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/blueprints/actionUtil.js#L259)

Comment: Yes but I don't want to use the request object, what if I'm coming from a `user` route and I want to know the `model` of a `post` record for example? Or what if I'm just running some server job using waterline lib without being inside sails?

Comment: In your own answer, you're referencing sails. How would your answer solve for a server using only waterline? Why would you not want to use the request object? In your question, are `post` and `user` associated?

Comment: Well I didn't flag my answer as valid because I want a less hacky way. In my answer I am using `sails` only because the list of defined models is at `sails.models`. If using only waterline it's then up to you to save the defined models at some place instead of `sails.models`.
I don't want to use the request object because I want to be able to determine the model of ANY record from ANY request or as I said outside of sails. The relation to `post` and `user` does not matter, they are just given as examples ;-) Thanks @Chetan Shenoy anyway.